# Reading ID3 tags from the web with C#

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib, id3, taglib-sharp

I've seen the TagLib Sharp example of how they read from a Gnome VFS, but does anyone know how or have sample code on how I can read an MP3 file from a website and get the ID3 info?

So say i have some MP3's and the link is like this: "http://myserver.com/indie/band1.mp3"

I'm trying to user TagLib Sharp to do this: http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp:_Examples

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to download the file locally and then run taglib against the local version.

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://myserver.com/indie/band1.mp3", "band1.mp3");
```

you could use the TagLib.File.IFileAbstraction, but I find downloading the file locally to be a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks Keivan, but I was hoping to just read it from the web. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: TagLib reads the beginning and the end of the file as far as I know looking for headers and audio properties. You may be able to provide it with specific byte ranges, but I have a feeling it would be super difficult. It may end up basically downloading the whole file by the time you're done fetching all the data it needs.

Comment: @jocull is mostly correct. Some file types, but definitely not mp3s only have key metadata at the front so they could theoretically be read without downloading the whole file.  That said, TagLib# doesn't guarantee a linear read though and depends on the stream being seekable. That typically isn't the case for download stream implementations.